# Form fields & Popup

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, thickbox

I'm developing a Drupal website,and in my add node form, I want the file upload fields (created with FileField) to be displayed in a thickbox-style popup. You just click on a "Add attachments" link, the popup comes in, and allows you to add the files. Then you close it, and submit the form normally.

Anyone knows of a nice module who can do that ? I tried Modal Frame, but it doesn't d anything...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jQuery UI and the dialog submodule. All you have to do is to write a small javascript, which opens the file upload element as a popup.